# Linux multi-thread, pausing one thread while continue running the other threads within the same process

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, delay, sleep

I cannot find a proper solution to my problem.

If i have more than one thread in one process. And I want to make only one thread to sleep while running the other threads within the same process, is there any predefined syntax for it or do i have to do my own implementation (sleep) ?

Ideally i want to send a indication from a thread to another thread when it is time for sleep.

Edited (2015-08-24)
I have two main threads, one for sending data over a network, the other receives the data from the network. Beside jitter, the receiving thread does validation and verification and some file management which in time could lead that it will drag behind. What i like to do is to add something like a micro sleep to the sender so that the receiver could catch up. sched_yield() will not help in this case because the HW has a multi core CPU with more than 40 cores.

Comment: You'll have to do your own implementation, but `sleep(3)` is generally not what you want in threads, because it may use signals (`SIGALRM`), and it is not guaranteed that `SIGALRM` is delivered to that same specific thread (if other threads are waiting on some signal, this may be problematic and your thread may sleep forever). You'll have to go for something more clever, e.g. `select(2)` with a FIFO or pipe. Can you elaborate your question? Include common use cases, why you want to do this, etc. This is important so that we can choose the right design.

Comment: I have two main threads, one for sending data over a network, the other receives the data from the network. Beside jitter, the receiving thread does validation and verification and some file management which in time could lead that it will drag behind. What i like to do is to add something like a micro sleep to the sender so that the receiver could catch up. sched_yield() will not help in this case because the HW has a multi core CPU with more than 40 cores.

Comment: I see. This is important, you should edit the question to include these details. I have added an answer that I believe is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description in the comments, it looks like you're trying to synchronize 2 threads so that one of them doesn't fall behind too far from the other.

If that's the case, you're going about this the wrong way. It is seldom a good idea to do synchronization by sleeping, because the scheduler may incur unpredictable and long delays that cause the other (slow) thread to remain stopped in the run queue without being scheduled. Even if it works most of the time, it's still a race condition, and it's an ugly hack.

Given your use case and constraints, I think you'd be better off using barriers (see `pthread_barrier_init(3)`). Pthread barriers allow you to create a rendezvous point in the code where threads can catch up.

You call `pthread_barrier_init(3)` as part of the initialization code, specifying the number of threads that will be synchronized using that barrier. In this case, it's 2.

Then, threads synchronize with others by calling `pthread_barrier_wait(3)`. The call blocks until the number of threads specified in `pthread_barrier_init(3)` call `pthread_barrier_wait(3)`, at which point every thread that was blocked in `pthread_barrier_wait(3)` becomes runnable and the cycle begins again. Essentially, barriers create a synchronization point where no one can move forward until everyone arrives. I think this is exactly what you're looking for.

Here's an example that simulates a fast sender thread and a slow receiver thread. They both synchronize with barriers to ensure that the sender does not do any work while the receiver is still processing other requests. The threads synchronize at the end of their work unit, but of course, you can choose where each thread calls `pthread_barrier_wait(3)`, thereby controlling exactly when (and where) threads synchronize.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

pthread_barrier_t barrier;

void *sender_thr(void *arg) {
    printf("Entered sender thread\n");

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        /* Simulate some work (500 ms) */
        if (usleep(500000) < 0) {
            perror("usleep(3) error");
        }

        printf("Sender thread synchronizing.\n");
        /* Wait for receiver to catch up */
        int barrier_res = pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
        if (barrier_res == PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD)
            printf("Sender thread was last.\n");
        else if (barrier_res == 0)
            printf("Sender thread was first.\n");
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "pthread_barrier_wait(3) error on sender: %s\n", strerror(barrier_res));
    }

    return NULL;
}

void *receiver_thr(void *arg) {
    printf("Entered receiver thread\n");

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        /* Simulate a lot of work */
        if (usleep(2000000) < 0) {
            perror("usleep(3) error");
        }

        printf("Receiver thread synchronizing.\n");
        /* Catch up with sender */
        int barrier_res = pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
        if (barrier_res == PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD)
            printf("Receiver thread was last.\n");
        else if (barrier_res == 0)
            printf("Receiver thread was first.\n");
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "pthread_barrier_wait(3) error on receiver: %s\n", strerror(barrier_res));
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    int barrier_res;
    if ((barrier_res = pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, 2)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_barrier_init(3) error: %s\n", strerror(barrier_res));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_t threads[2];

    int thread_res;
    if ((thread_res = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, sender_thr, NULL)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create(3) error on sender thread: %s\n", strerror(thread_res));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((thread_res = pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, receiver_thr, NULL)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create(3) error on receiver thread: %s\n", strerror(thread_res));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Do some work... */

    if ((thread_res = pthread_join(threads[0], NULL)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join(3) error on sender thread: %s\n", strerror(thread_res));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((thread_res = pthread_join(threads[1], NULL)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join(3) error on receiver thread: %s\n", strerror(thread_res));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((barrier_res = pthread_barrier_destroy(&barrier)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_barrier_destroy(3) error: %s\n", strerror(barrier_res));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that, as specified in the manpage for `pthread_barrier_wait(3)`, once the desired number of threads call `pthread_barrier_wait(3)`, the barrier state is reset to the original state that was in use after the last call to `pthread_barrier_init(3)`, which means that the barrier atomically unlocks and resets state, so it is always ready for the next synchronization point, which is wonderful.

Once you're done with the barrier, don't forget to free the associated resources with `pthread_barrier_destroy(3)`.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I have a question. In this sample the barrier is initiated to handle two threads. What if one of the threads does not call for wait_barrier, will the process end up in a deadlock?

Comment: @Zäta The other thread will wait forever. `pthread_barrier_wait(3)` will block until those two threads call it. If one of them doesn't call it, the other will block forever.

Comment: If one thread call the pthread_barrier_wait() and the second thread unexpectedly terminates. Is it possible to cancel a barrier wait for the first thread?

Comment: @Zäta In general, no, there's no way to cancel. If you really need that, you'd need to do some fancy things with signals and `longjmp(3)` for example, but perhaps a better choice is to ensure that threads don't terminate unexpectedly when others are waiting - this is true for most, if not all, synchronization primitives.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.